# why the styling is not working after replace html by js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code and current [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w250I.png). The items that expected to be inside the table went outside.

my html code

```
        <table class="items-container">
            <tr>
                <th>Item description</th>
                <th>Price(HK$)</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total price(HK$)</th>
            </tr>
            <div id="cart-items">
                <!-- <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>chocolate cookies</p>
                        <p class="small-description-text">100g</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>$50</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>$50</td>
                </tr> -->
            </div>
        </table>
```

js code

```
    <script>
        let cartItemsArray = [{title:"chocolate",price:50,qty:2,id:"001"},{title:"oat",price:60,qty:1,id:"002"}];
        document.getElementById('cart-items').innerHTML = cartItemsArray
            .map(
                (item) =>
                    `<tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>${item.title}</p>
                        <p class="small-description-text">100g</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>$${item.price}</td>
                    <td>${item.qty}</td>
                    <td>${item.qty * item.price}</td>
                </tr>`
            )
            .join('');
    </script>
```

css code

```
    <style>
        .items-container {
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 1.2rem;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table th {
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }
        table th,
        td {
            font-family: var(--fontCommon);
            padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
            font-weight: 400;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            text-align: left;
        }

        td .small-description-text {
            margin-top: 5px;
            font-size: 1rem;
            color: grey;
            font-family: var(--fontId);
        }
    </style>
```

When I try to use the html code direcly (uncomment the element inside .cart-items), it show perfectly like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5jor.png). What is the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

A [validator](https://validator.nu/) would reveal your problem.

`div` elements are not allowed as children of `table` elements. `tr` elements are not allowed as children of `div` elements.

The version of your code with the `tr` already in place hits browser error recovery and the `div` is moved outside the table.

The version of your code where the `tr` is added by JavaScript tries to add the `tr` to the `div` *after* it has been moved outside the table.

---

Add the `tr` by using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) on the implicit `tbody` element instead of `innerHTML` on a `div` which can't be where you want it.

```js
const content = `<tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>chocolate cookies</p>
                        <p class="small-description-text">100g</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>$50</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>$50</td>
                </tr>`;
                
document.querySelector('.items-container tbody').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", content)
```

```css
th, td { border: dotted #aaa 1px; }
```

```html
<table class="items-container">
  <tr>
    <th>Item description</th>
    <th>Price(HK$)</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Total price(HK$)</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```